# Как узнать, чем занята вся память в windows 7?

Tags: память, windows-7

Как узнать, кто съел всю память? 4Гб. Тут в любом столбике в сумме столько нет...

[image: task manager screen 1/2]
[image: task manager screen 2/2]]

Comment: Диспетчер задач в семёрке - слабенький инструмент для анализа. Возьмите [ProcessExplorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) или что-нить аналогичное.

Answer (score 2):

Кажется это то, что вы ищете:

[image: ресурсы ОС]

Так же процессы можно отсортировать по потреблению ресурсов.

На вашей системе нужно найти и запустить программу `resmon.exe`. Больше информации [тут](http://www.oszone.net/10487/resmon)

Comment: Да. он называется "монитор ресурсов" в windows 7. Не помогает. Запихал скрины https://imgur.com/a/UgGfX2E в распознаватель и посчитал сумму по каждому столбцу -- {0: 2511967, 1: 1630621, 2: 498540, 3: 1061011}. Ну нету 4Гб нигде...

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin странно как-то. Может утечка памяти? Хотя ОС это все фиксирует и тогда бы мы 4ГБ увидели. Действительно, попробуйте сторонний софт для наблюдения за системой, например [этот](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/).